# Al usar ROWNUM para filtrar entre valor mínimo y máximo devuelve 0 resultados

Tags: sql, oracle

Debido a un volumen altisimo de datos, tenemos que paginar una consulta SQL.

**Mi objetivo:**
Recuperar registros entre los parámetros dados Ej:`VALOR1 = 123, VALOR2=223`
Ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLA
WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN VALOR1 AND VALOR2 --Da lo mismo que use ROWNUM>1 o BETWEEN
```

**PROBLEMA:**
Cuando el VALOR1 es 0, me devuelve los resultados que busco.
Cuando el VALOR1 es mayor que 1, no devuelve ninguna fila.

También he probado esto:

```
SELECT * FROM(
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLA
)WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN VALOR1 AND VALOR2
```

Y sigue sin mostrar registros siempre que VALOR1 es mayor que 1.

Comment: Ya probaste en el WHERE poner "WHERE ROWNUM<=VALOR1 AND ROWNUM>=VALOR2"?
No sé a qué se deba tu problema pero a lo mejor eso puede funcionar

Comment: Hola @AEFA19 gracias por tu respuesta, pero ya había probado eso y no ha funcionado. `--Da lo mismo que use ROWNUM>1 o BETWEEN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es la forma adecuada de usar `ROWNUM`, debiera ser así:

```
SELECT * 
       FROM (SELECT *, 
                    ROWNUM RN
                    FROM TABLA
            )
       WHERE RN BETWEEN VALOR1 AND VALOR2
```

El `rownum` se "materializa" dentro de la subconsulta.

Comment: Perfecto, era lo que estaba buscando!

Answer (score 2):

Eso que tratas de hacer no es posible ya que la columna "ROWNUM" se crea al vuelo, piensa esto.
Internamente lo que hace el motor de base de datos es crear un indice virtual el cual nombra como "ROWNUM" y en el que dice por ejemplo

```
select * from tabla where ROWNUM between 1 and 5;
```

lo primero que hace internamente le agrega un valor numérico a la columna "ROWNUM", por ejemplo la tabla tiene 5 registros, entonces crea su tabla virtual

```
ROWNUM   Columna1
  1         Registro 1
  2         Registro 2
  3         Registro 3
  4         Registro 4
  5         Registro 5
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, en cambio tu quieres hacer esto:

```
select * from tabla where ROWNUM between 2 and 5;
```

lo cual el motor no es posible de procesar por que internamente te debería traer apartir del segundo registro ¿pero de que?
internamente es imposible para el motor crearte un indice a partir del registro 2, es ilógico para él, para el motor de base de datos la manera correcta es comenzar su indice a partir del 1, no de 2 o 3.

Que haría yo en tu caso si quieres hacer eso sería crear una tabla en la cual pones un campo como identidad (numérico consecutivo) poblarla con tus información y sobre esa ya metería el filtro que buscas, de otro modo no le veo como.

Comment: Tras hacer las pruebas había imaginado que los creaba sobre la marcha, pero gracias por confirmarlo ;)