# ¿alguien sabe de un script para limitar cantidad de datos traídos de una base de datos?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

buen dia, me gustaria saber si alguien sabe de algun script que me permita consultar solo cierta cantidad de datos de la base de datos y que le permita al usuario decidir con un botón o algo cargar mas datos, ya que al hacer el SELECT * FROM me trae todo pero  quiero que solo de entrada me muestre solo una pequeña cantidad de datos, les agradeceria me pudiesen ayudar con ese script, gracias

Comment: Acota la consulta... Ejemplo: `SELECT id, last_name, first_name FROM table_name WHERE is_pro=1 LIMIT 10`

Comment: A leer y practicar: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/index.htm y seguir practicando. Buena suerte

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor trata siempre de colocar en la descripción de tu pregunta el código relacionado necesario como para que los demás integrantes de la comunidad podamos depurarlo y colaborarte mejor en la solución del problema. Un saludo!

Comment: Por favor si van a dar negativo coloquen un comentario que le haga saber al usuario NUEVO el motivo así puede corregir su error. Dificilmente pueda corregir algo si ni le explican cual es su falla

Comment: Plantee una pregunta similar a esta hace un mes, tal vez te sirva de ayuda: [Al usar ROWNUM para filtrar entre valor mínimo y máximo devuelve 0 resultados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162910/al-usar-rownum-para-filtrar-entre-valor-m%C3%ADnimo-y-m%C3%A1ximo-devuelve-0-resultados)

Comment: OscarR muchas gracias viejo me funciono perfectamente, y gracias por sus consejos muy útiles la verdad, ahora me nace otra inquietud si quiero que el usuario decida cargar mas comentarios ¿como puedo hacerlo?        
$consultar = "SELECT * FROM drifters ORDER BY fecha_y_hora DESC  LIMIT 4";

$resultado = $conexion -> query($consultar);

if($resultado -> num_rows > 0){
    
  while ($row = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
   
<div align="center">
  <input type="text" name="coment" disabled="" style="width:700px; height:200px;"  value="<?php echo $row['comentario'] ?>">
</div>

Answer (score 2):

Como bien dice **@OscaR** en su comentario puedes utilizar `LIMIT` para obtener un número determinado de registros de una consulta. Para efectos de MySQL sería algo así:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Ordenes LIMIT 30";
```

La consulta anterior se lee: "Selecciona toda los campos de la tabla `Ordenes` sólo 30 registros"

> Generalmente se combina el LIMIT con ORDER BY para obtener los últimos
>   "n" registros.

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM Ordenes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30";
```

La consulta anterior se lee: " Selecciona el id de los últimos 30 registros de la tabla `Ordenes` según su id. Suponiendo que tengas 50 registros en tu tabla ordenes (id 1-50) entonces esta consulta te traería como resultado:

```
id
50
49
48
...
...
...
20
```

Si quisieras empezar "saltando" ciertos registros podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM Ordenes ORDER BY id LIMIT 30 OFFSET 10";
```

La consulta anterior se leería: "Selecciona el id de los últimos 30 registros después de los primeros 10 obtenidos". Entonces nuevamente si tienes un total de 50 registros (id máximo 50) entonces el resultado sería:

```
id
40
39
38
...
...
...
10
```

Para más información podrías chequear: [PHP MySQL LIMIT](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

**Actualización:** En vista que no queda muy claro lo que necesitas en tu descripción de preguntas y a la sugerencia que dió en comentarios el Sr. Cedano explicaré como puedes lograr mostrar registros de manera "externa a la base de datos o al SGBD" con ***paginación***.

La ***paginación*** consiste en tomar cierto número de registros provenientes (por ejemplo) de una consulta a base de datos y organizarlos de manera tal que no todos se muestren a la vez sino de forma segmentada.

Por ejemplo si tienes un total de 50 registros obtenidos de la consulta a base de datos puede que quieras mostrar de 10 en 10 registros en la vista bien sea por comodidad, para mejorar la interacción del usuario con tu sitio, responsividad, entre otros.

> Para ello te propongo una herramienta bastante extendida denominada
>   ***Datatables*** de las cuales utilizan la librería jQuery. Para más
>   información puedes chequear lo siguiente: [jQuery datatables](https://datatables.net)

A continuación un ejemplo de implementación de las ***datatables***:

```
<table id="data_viaje" role="grid" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead style="background-color:#ffffff">
    <tr>
        <th>CÓDIGO</th>
        <th>PLAZAS</th>
        <th>ORIGEN</th>
        <th>DESTINO</th>
        <th>PRECIO</th>
        <th style="width:10%">MODIFICAR</th>
        <th style="width:10%">ELIMINAR</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php foreach($resultado as $result => $viaje){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $viaje['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $viaje['numero_plaza'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $viaje['origen'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $viaje['destino'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $viaje['precio'];?></td>
            <td><span id="modificar_viaje" name='modificar_viaje' class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil modificar"></span></td>
            <td><span id="modificar_viaje" name='modificar_viaje' class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove eliminar"></span></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

</tbody>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
$('#data_viaje').DataTable({
    "language":{
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página",
        "zeroRecords": "No existe registros asociados a la busqueda",
        "info": "Página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "No existe registro disponible",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros en total)",
        "search":"Buscar:",
        "paginate": {
            "first":      "Primero",
            "last":       "Último",
            "next":       "Siguiente",
            "previous":   "Anterior"
        }
    },
    "lengthMenu": [4,8,12],
    responsive: true
});
</script>
```

Básicamente lo que te muestro en mi ejemplo anterior es una tabla común y corriente en **HTML** cuyo contenido (cada fila despues de la primera que muestra el título) será generado mediante **PHP** extrayendo de la variable `$resultado` (que es la variable que guarda el resultado de nuestra consulta a base de edatos) la información necesaria registro a registro.

Ahora donde entra la parte de paginación? En el `<script></script>` que se encuentra al final del archivo. Es bastante simple sólo haces referencia al `id` de tu tabla para inicializar la ***Datatable*** y le pasas los parametros. El parametro en particular que te interesaría (el número de filas por página) sería `"lengthMenu": [4,8,12]`. En mi ejemplo muestro 4, 8 o 12 registros (según lo que seleccione el usuario) por página. La ***datatable*** generará automáticamente la ***paginación*** según este parametro.

Espero sea de ayuda. Un Saludo

Comment: Una respuesta más que correcta para una deficiente pregunta. Mi +1. Gracias por la mención ;-).

Comment: De nada @OscarR, gracias a tí por valorar mi esfuerzo y por ser de hecho el primero que ofreció un ejemplo práctico para encaminar al OP a solucionar el problema. Un saludo!

Comment: La respuesta es correcta en cuanto a limitar los resultados, pero, de acuerdo a esta afirmación de la pregunta:  *...  y que le permita al usuario decidir con un botón o algo **cargar mas datos** ...*, lo que parece necesitar es implementar una solución tipo [paginación](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928), que permita desplazamiento por grupos de resultados.

Comment: Gracias por su acotación Sr. Cedano. Actualizaré mir respuesta para agregar paginación

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya tome su recomendación y coloqué también la explicación sobre paginación. Nuevamente gracias por su acotación. Un saludo